# Grails "respond" renders the wrong view when launched from .war file

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

A Grails application has a lot of auto-generated (from standard Grails 2.3.0 scaffolding) code using the new RESTful "respond" feature. For example, the index methods generally look like this:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Alpha.list(params), model:[alphaInstanceCount: Alpha.count()]
}
```

This works completely fine when the application is run as "grails run-app" however fails when the application is packaged as a .war and launched that way inside a non-embedded servlet container.

It works for the first controller/view combination used, but for subsequent ones uses the view folder of the first view rendered. E.g., if we try `/alpha/index` first, and then afterwards `/beta/index` then the `/alpha/index` will work fine, but `/beta/index` will use `/alpha/index.gsp` for rendering (instead of the expected `/beta/index.gsp`).

If, however, I change the method to:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    render(view: 'index', model:[alphaInstanceList: Alpha.list(params), alphaInstanceCount: Alpha.count()])
}
```

then it works fine in both deployment options.

I added some debug code to some of the .gsp-s to output `${this.getGroovyPageFileName()}`, `${controllerName}` and  `${actionName}`.

That shows that while the controller and action names are always the expected ones, the view used on views rendered after the first one remains the view used on the first one.

For example, the initial invocation for `/alpha/index` has controller as `alpha`, action as `index`, and view as `/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/alpha/index.gsp`, however the ***consequent invocation*** of `/beta/index` has controller as `beta`, view as `index`, but view as `/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/alpha/index.gsp` (***note the wrong "alpha" here***). Consequent invocations of `alpha` remain fine.

If we had started with beta, and then moved to alpha, it would have been the other way around (`beta` is fine, `alpha` is broken).

I tried running it unders JPDA but while my IDE appears to be connecting it is not actually hitting any breakpoints (probably unrelated issue).

I'm using Grails 2.3.0, JDK 1.6, and Tomcat7.

There is nothing bad that I can see in the logs.

Any ideas what the issue may be, or even just how to approach debugging it?

http://goo.gl/aFKYYb <-- grails app

http://goo.gl/aDP6Lx <-- .war file

Comment: I am seeing this exact same behavior.  I thought it was a Heroku issue, but looks like it may be Grails in general.  Thanks for the workaround by converting calls to "respond" to "render"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Grails defect (although they cannot reproduce):

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10614

I did a "install-templates" and am modifying the scaffolding templates as a work-around.

Edit - yes, confirmed; I forgot to update this response but upgrade to 2.3.1 solves the issue, as per the defect linked.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Grails 2.3.1 fixed this problem for me.  (Reading the defect you posted pointed me in the right direction - thanks.)

Note that you will also have to upgrade your hibernate plugin to version 3.6.10.2, or you will get an error message similar to "Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application."