# Getting 404 error when i am submitting data not in the database in a groovy grails framework

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

This is my gsp page which works fine when i submit it with values in the data base  but fails when i query it with some data not in the db .Ideally it should show result not found but it gives me a blank page with 404 error ???

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<g:set var="entityName"
    value="${message(code: 'booking.label', default: 'Booking')}" />
<title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div id="check-status" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">

                <h1 align="center">Check Booking Status</h1>
                <br> <br>
                <div class="row row-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    <i class="fa fa-money"></i> Enter Details For Checking Booking
                                    Status
                                </h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <g:form action='check' ,controller='Booking'>
                                    <table align="center">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div
                                                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: bookingInstance, field: 'bookingNo', 'error')} required">
                                                    <label for="bookingNo"> <g:message
                                                            code="booking.bookingNo.label" default="Booking No" /> <span
                                                        class="required-indicator">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <g:textField name="bookingNo" required=""
                                                        value="${params.bookingNo}" placeholder="Enter BOOKING NO" />
                                                </div> <br>
                                            </td>

                                            <td width="50%">
                                                <div
                                                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: bookingInstance, field: 'firstBuyerPhone', 'error')} required">
                                                    <label for="firstBuyerPhone"> <g:message
                                                            code="booking.firstBuyerPhone.label"
                                                            default="First Buyer Phone" /> <span
                                                        class="required-indicator">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <g:textField name="firstBuyerPhone" required=""
                                                        value="${params.firstBuyerPhone}"
                                                        placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />
                                                </div> <br>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <g:submitButton name="check" class="btn btn-success"
                                            value="${message(code: 'default.button.check.label', default: 'Check Booking Status')}" />

                                    </fieldset>
                                </g:form>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div>           
                            <g:if test ="${bookingInstance!=null}">

                                    <h3>Booking Details</h3>
                                    <table  align="left">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>First Buyer Email Id </b>${bookingInstance.firstBuyerEmailId }
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Second Buyer Email Id </b>${bookingInstance.secondBuyerEmailId }
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Discount  </b>${bookingInstance.discount }
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Taxes </b>${ bookingInstance.taxes}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Booking Date  </b><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                                    date="${bookingInstance.bookingDate}" />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Plot No </b>${bookingInstance.home.plotNo }
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b> Home Type  </b>${bookingInstance.home.homeType }
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Associate Name  </b><g:each  var="property" status="status"
                                                    in="${bookingInstance.associates.name}">

                                                    <g:if test="${status != 0}">
                                                    ${"," }
                                                     </g:if>

                                                    ${property}
                                                </g:each>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Payment Schedule Name  </b><g:each var="property" status="status"
                                                    in="${bookingInstance.paymentSchedules.name}">

                                                    <g:if test="${status != 0}">
                                                    ${"," }
                                                     </g:if>

                                                    ${property}

                                                </g:each>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Payment Schedule Amount </b> <g:each var="property" status="status"
                                                    in="${bookingInstance.paymentSchedules.amount}">

                                                    <g:if test="${status != 0}">
                                                    ${"," }
                                                     </g:if>

                                                    ${property}

                                                </g:each></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Payment Schedule DueDate </b><g:each var="property" status="status"
                                                    in="${bookingInstance.paymentSchedules.dueDate}">


                                                    <g:if test="${status != 0}">
                                                    ${"," }
                                                     </g:if>
                                                    <g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${property}" />


                                                </g:each>
                                        </tr>


                                    </table>

                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${bookingInstance==null }">
                                Result Not Found 
                                </g:if>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the method which i am calling in my Bookingcontroller is

```
def check(){
        if(request.method == 'POST')    {
            def bookingNo=params.bookingNo as Integer
            def firstBuyerPhoneNo=params.firstBuyerPhone

            println "booking number"+bookingNo+" PhoneNumber"+firstBuyerPhoneNo
            Booking bookingInstance = null
            try {

                bookingInstance=bookingService.findByFirstBuyerPhoneAndBookingNo(firstBuyerPhoneNo,bookingNo)

            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            respond bookingInstance
        }
    }


I have just no clue that what the problem is in the form or in my controller ?
```

Comment: If you are using grails 2.3.0 it seems to be an issue with respond [as per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333311/grails-respond-renders-the-wrong-view-when-launched-from-war-file), Upgrading to Grails 2.3.1 can fix this problem. Workaround would be to change respond to render and pass view and model to it.

Comment: What Grails version do you use? 404 means NOT FOUND. What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I am using Grails 2.2.4 .and the expected behavior is showing the Result Not Found String on the same page as mentioned in gsp page that when the model value is null it should simply print this message

Comment: am not sure but you have to use view in case of HTML rendering with respond with a object..

Comment: Thanks guys using render() works good enough for me .